# 400 (Bad Request) on passing JSON to Spring controller

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc, post

I am trying to pass array of objects as JSON string to the Spring controller. My data in JSON format looks like

```
[{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "First Item"
},
{
    "id": 78910,
    "name": "Second Item"
}]
```

So I am sending to controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/url", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void doSomething(@RequestBody List<CustInfo> myCustInfoList) {
    System.out.println("Message Received " + myCustInfoList);
}
```

with this AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/some/url',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: '[{"id": 123456, "name": "First Item"}, {"id": 78910, "name": "Second Item"}]',
  success: function () {
            consloe.log("Success");
           }
});
```

For this I have two beans `OuterCover` and `CustInfo`. Where `OuterCover` has list of `CustInfo` and `CustInfo` has `id` and `name`.

```
public class OuterCover {

  List<CustInfo> myCustInfoList;

  //getter & setter

}
```

But I am getting 400 (Bad Request) on this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose OuterCover class into other class as the request has OuterCover element. E.g.

```
class RequestDto{

    @JsonElement("outerCover")
    private OuterCover outerCover;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Alternatively, you can modify the request payload and remove 'outerCover' element e.g.:

```
[{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "First Item"
},
{
    "id": 78910,
    "name": "Second Item"
}]
```

Comment: What if I want to send as `data: {[{"id": 123456, "name": "First Item"},{"id": 78910, "name": "Second Item"}]}`

Comment: That will work, I have added another solution in my answer.

Comment: Can't I just use `OutCover` in controller? I want to avoid need to create one more class (`RequestDto`).

Comment: In that case, you need to modify the request payload as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Removing `outerCover` still gives me 400. See updated JSON .

Comment: Change your request json to `{\"myCustInfoList\" : [{\"id\": 123456, \"name\": \"First Item\"}, {\"id\": 78910, \"name\": \"Second Item\"}]}` and it would work.